# Is there a way to use python debugger in airflow dags?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler, pdb, ipdb

I am running airflow locally without docker or helm, and am using SequentialExecutor as the executor, I want to use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) or [ipdb](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/) debugger inside callable functions of PythonOperator. is there a way for it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so, but there actually is a [debug executor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/debug.html)

Answer (score 0):

which airflow version are you running?

since version 2.5 you can debug locally without any executors with `dag.test()`

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/debug.html#testing-dags-with-dag-test

(if you don't already have a local DB, initialize it with `airflow db check && airflow db migrate`)